# test for membership in mandelbrot bulb of period n

Tags: fractals

Is there a efficient test (formula or inequality) of whether a given point is in a bulb of period n?  In other words, something other than running the iteration a lot of times to see if it converges to a period n cycle. I would like to apply such a method (if it exists) to writing some code.

Answer (score 2):

A point is interior to a component of period $n$ if it is not interior to any component of lower period and:

$$\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial z} f_c^n(z_0)\right| \le 1 \text{, where} \\
f_c^n(z_0) = z_0$$

Given $n$, it's possible to find $z_0$ by Newton's method.  Testing every $n$ from $1$ to maximum iteration limit is expensive, so an optimisation is to only test $n$ where $|z_n|$ reaches a new minimum.

More info in my blog post on [practical interior distance rendering](http://mathr.co.uk/blog/2014-11-02_practical_interior_distance_rendering.html).

**EDIT**

If $c_1$ is in a period $n$ component, you can use Newton's method to find the nucleus of the component $c_0$ which satisfies $f_{c_0}^n(0) = 0$ (treating $f_c$ as a function of $c$, this time).  Then you can compute a size estimate:

```
complex double size(complex double nucleus, int period) {
  complex double l = 1;
  complex double b = 1;
  complex double z = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < period; ++i) {
    z = z * z + nucleus;
    l = 2 * z * l;
    b = b + 1 / l;
  }
  return 1 / (b * l * l);
}
```

For "circular" bulbs (almost all are not true circles), the magnitude of this size estimate (call it $d$) is approximately the diameter.  Then for any $c_2$ you can do a simple circle inclusion test, say $k = \frac{2}{d}|c_2 - c_0| - 1$ then when $k < 0$ it's probably in the same bulb and when $k > 0$ it's probably not in the same bulb - $|k|$ gives a vague measure of certainty.

If you don't know the shape of the component, that's possible to find too, using the formula in Eq 5.8 in ["On the shapes of elementary domains or why Mandelbrot Set is made from almost ideal circles?" by V.Dolotin, A.Morozov](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0701234):

```
shape_t shape(complex double nucleus, int period) {
  complex double z = nucleus;
  complex double dc = 1;
  complex double dz = 1;
  complex double dcdc = 0;
  complex double dcdz = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < period; ++i) {
    dcdc = 2 * (z * dcdc + dc * dc);
    dcdz = 2 * (z * dcdz + dc * dz);
    dc = 2 * z * dc + 1;
    dz = 2 * z * dz;
    z = z * z + nucleus;
  }
  complex double e = - (dcdc / (2 * dc) + dcdz / dz) / (dc * dz);
  if (cabs(e) < cabs(e - 1)) {
    return cardioid;
  } else {
    return circle;
  }
}
```

There might be a way to apply cardioid interior testing by using the complex result of the size estimate to transform $c_2$ to the corresponding point relative to the main period 1 cardioid - but the distortion of cardioids is quite apparent near cusps, so this probably wouldn't work very well.

The code in this answer is taken from my (pre-alpha) mandelbrot-numerics library:
<strike>https://gitorious.org/mandelbrot</strike> http://code.mathr.co.uk/mandelbrot-numerics

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.  So it appears that one way or the other one needs to do iterations, in this case Newton's method.  I will have to study your blog to understand this approach.  In the equations you give, c is the point one is testing, and Zo is one of the points in the period n cycle, correct?  What about an approach where if you know that a value C1 is in the period n bulb, there might an efficient (non-iterating) test for a nearby point C2 being in the same bulb. I recall from a Wikipedia article something about perturbation methods.  This kind of sounds like what I am talking about, but I am not sure.  I will have to study up on perturbation methods.

Comment: I expanded my answer with more info on your C1/C2 question.  Perturbation methods are more to do with time-optimisation by reducing high precision calculations needed for really deep zooms.

Comment: Do you know the algorithm for finding Taylor series approximations of the bulb borders?  Your blog site does not have it that I can tell.

Comment: No.  Do you?  I've [traced boundaries using Newton's method in two variables](http://code.mathr.co.uk/mandelbrot-numerics/blob/HEAD:/c/lib/m_d_interior.c), and failed to understand ["A parameterization of the period 3 hyperbolic components of the Mandelbrot set" by Dante Giarrusso and Yuval Fisher](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1995-123-12/S0002-9939-1995-1301497-3/S0002-9939-1995-1301497-3.pdf)